# Is there a way of rotating ImageTk after it has been defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.9

rather than writing something along the lines of:

```
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
```

it would be far more effective in my code to use something like:

```
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image).rotate(angle)
```

as all of the images are set up before hand and would be near impossible to change later. Is there anyway of doing this? Or even some kind of way to get the file name from a [`PhotoImage()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) such as retrieving `'name.png'` from

```
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='name.png')
```

Even that would be much simpler than recreating every single imported `PhotoImage()` whenever I want to rotate them.

Comment: No I dont think its possible, `PhotoImage` just takes an image and makes it into a format that tkinter identifies, I dont think it has to allow to use properties like rotate, resize, etc. Maybe if you state the need you want to achieve we could find a way around.

Comment: Hundreds of ImageTk.PhotoImage() variables are set up in a separate images.py file and are imported into the main script. I want to be able to rotate them in the main script and then put them onto the canvas.
for example if:
IMAGE=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Image.png')
was in the images.py file, I'd want to be able to rotate it in the main file without simply changing only using information from the initial variable. This may be impossible as you say.

Comment: If there are any patterns in this image file, why not just loop through it rather than creating 100s of variables and create `Image.open()` instances. Only when you want to change to tkinter image use `PhotoImage`.

Comment: yes, I suppose that is possible although it's gonna be tedious to do :D Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Since you're using Python, it would be possible to add a `file_path` attribute to a `PhotoImage` object after you create one. You could also attach an unrotated "master" version of the image to it so you wouldn't need to reload it (assuming you have enough RAM).